# Spring WebFlux - Send HTTP requests with WebClient for each element of a list inside a Mono

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

We are trying to convert an MVC, resttemplate, blocking, application into a WebFlux app.

Very straightforward in the “blocking world”, get a list inside a request payload, iterate through it and send N http requests to a third party rest API.

Very important it is a third party rest API, no control over it at all, and cannot ask them to implement a version taking the list, it has to be one by one.

Trivial with resttemplate, what would be the WebFlux equivalent please?
This is a bit challenging, since it takes a Mono and returns a Mono.
A small snippet will be great.

Thank you

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class QuestionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuestionApplication.class, args);
    }

    @PostMapping("question")
    MyResponse question(@RequestBody MyRequest myRequest) {
        List<String>  myStrings = myRequest.getListOfString();
        List<Integer> myIds     = iterateAndSendRequestOneByOneGetIdFromString(myStrings);
        return new MyResponse(myIds);
    }

    private List<Integer> iterateAndSendRequestOneByOneGetIdFromString(List<String> myStrings) {
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : myStrings) {
            Integer id = new RestTemplate().postForObject("http://external-service:8080/getOneIdFromOneString", string, Integer.class);
            ids.add(id);
        }
        return ids;
    }

//    @PostMapping("how-to-do-the-same-with-WebFlux-WebClient-please?")
//    Mono<MyResponse> question(@RequestBody Mono<MyRequest> myRequestMono) {
//        return null;
//    }

}

class MyResponse {
    private List<Integer> myIds;
}

class MyRequest {
    private List<String> strings;
}
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is to use `flatMap` from Flux.

```
public Mono<MyResponse> getIdsFromStrings(MyRequest myRequest) {

  WebClient client =
      WebClient.builder().baseUrl("http://external-service:8080").build();

  return Flux.fromIterable(myRequest.getStrings())
      .flatMap(s -> client.post().uri("/getOneIdFromOneString").body(s, String.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(Integer.class))
      .collectList()
      .map(MyResponse::new);
}
```

`.flatMap` is an asynchronous operation and will execute your requests concurrently. You can also choose to set concurrency limits by using an overloaded method of `flatMap` (refer to documentation).